# Why is it beneficial to remove tail recursion?

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, recursion, data-structures

Just an overall data structures question: Why is it beneficial to remove tail recursion specifically in a quick sort even if it doesn't change complexity?

Comment: Because each recursive call grows the call stack

Comment: A bit more context would be nice. Where did you hear this? In addition to the obvious benefit mentioned by HAL9000, quicksort only grows the stack log(n) frames so the input array would need to be awfully long to blow the stack on most environments.

Comment: There are languages that have a tail recursion optimization required by the language, so that the stack won't overflow.  But neither C nor C++ have that as a required optimization, and all C and C++ compilers that I've used do not have a tail recursion optimization.  I presume because it is difficult to implement for C and C++, and not because the compiler vendors don't want to.

Comment: The main reason I see for removing tail recursion is that in iterative solutions it is generally easier to understand what is going on.

Comment: @Eljay gcc and clang both have tail recursion optimization. I strongly suspect msvc and icc also have this. What compilers are you talking about that don't have this optimizations? It's actually pretty simple to detect and optimize tail recursion.

Comment: You're probably referring to the compiler optimization called tail recursion elimination.

The idea is that if you can turn a recursive call into, effectively, a loop, then you don't have to reserve stack space for the recursive call.

Comment: @bolov • Tumbleweed53 is correct, that is what I'm referring to.

Answer (score 7):

Quicksort takes O(N<sup>2</sup>) time in the worst case.

In that worst case, if each call recurses separately on both halves, it also takes O(N) stack space.

That is too much space to waste on the call stack.

Practical implementations of quicksort recurse on the *smaller* half, and then loop to sort the larger half.  This limits the worst case stack consumption to O(log N) in the worst case, which is quite reasonable.

If you get called to sort an array with 100000000 items, it's OK if your calls go 27 levels deep, but it's definitely not OK of they go 10000000 levels deep.

Answer (score 4):

@Matt Timmermans’ answer is great and goes into a lot of detail. I wanted to add one more bit to the answer. You asked this:

> Why is it beneficial to remove tail recursion specifically in a quick sort even if it doesn't change complexity?

Tail call elimination doesn’t change (asymptotic) ***time*** complexity, but it does change ***space*** complexity. While the big-O runtime of the code won’t change, the amount of space needed will shrink pretty significantly, and that’s important because space is limited (especially for the call stack).

One other detail: the cost of calling a function on many processor architectures is higher than that of a normal loop due to the cost of passing parameters, saving information about the return address, etc. So tail call elimination sometimes does improve the runtime, though only by a constant factor and not in a big-O sense.